# Angular Resolve on Application Reload

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-promise

How do I delay initialization of my Application Controller (a la the 'resolve' attribute in the router) on a page reload? Or perhaps the better question, how do I delay the view till my controller has retrieved the user object, specifically on page reloads?

I currently have this at the top of my ApplicationCtrl

```
if (localStorage.getItem('token') && localStorage.getItem('token') != 'null')
{
    sessionStorage.setItem('token', localStorage.getItem('token'))
}
if (sessionStorage.getItem('token') && sessionStorage.getItem('token') != 'null')
{
    UserSvc.getUser()
    .then(function (response) 
    {
        loadUser(response.data)
    })
    .then(function (error)
    {
        if (error) $scope.logout()
    })
}
```

This checks for an auth token, and then gets the user object from the database using that token.

But the problem is the user data stutters in after the page has appeared, so that our nav-bar is empty before the user's display name suddenly appears a few milliseconds afterward.

How can I delay the display of this view till the initial user request has completed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. I just created a top level $scope boolean $scope.initResolved which is rendered true by a completion of that first user check (whether it retrieves a user or not) and set the header and ng-view to ng-if="initResolved"

```
$scope.initResolved = false

    if (localStorage.getItem('token') && localStorage.getItem('token') != 'null')
    {
        sessionStorage.setItem('token', localStorage.getItem('token'))
    }
    if (sessionStorage.getItem('token') && sessionStorage.getItem('token') != 'null')
    {
        UserSvc.getUser()
        .then(function (response) 
        {
            loadUser(response.data)
            $scope.initResolved = true
        })
        .then(function (error)
        {
            if (error) $scope.logout()
            $scope.initResolved = true
        })
    }
    else if ($location.url() == "")
    {
        $location.path('/welcome')
        $scope.initResolved = true
    }
    else $scope.initResolved = true
```

Answer (score 1):

This would then should be putted in `resolve` of you state, the customService will return `UserStatus` that will contain promise object. Then in you could add this service to your controller, and `controller` will wait till this dependence get resolved.

```
resolve: function() {
    'UserStatus': function(UserSvc) {
        if (localStorage.getItem('token') && localStorage.getItem('token') != 'null') {
            sessionStorage.setItem('token', localStorage.getItem('token'))
        }
        if (sessionStorage.getItem('token') && sessionStorage.getItem('token') != 'null') {
            return UserSvc.getUser();
        }
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
app.controller('myCtrl', function(UserStatus, $scope){
   UserStatus.then(function(data){
      //you will get response here
   })
})
```